# Jquery setTimeout cause Chrome to hang / crash

Tags: settimeout

I use this code to display my animation, when I am in chrome, wait for 10~40 minutes later, the browser will hang/crash, what's the problem? Can someone help me?

```
$(function(){
$(".card_up,.girl,.card_down").css({"position":"absolute"})
$(".card_up").fadeIn(300).animate({top: 800}).animate({top: -15},1200);
$(".girl").fadeIn(300).animate({top: -800}).animate({top: -90},900).animate({top:  -131},500);
$(".card_down").fadeIn(300).animate({top:-300}).animate({top:0},2000).animate({top: 20},2000);

function UU(){
    $(".card_up").animate({top: 15},1000).animate({top: 5},2000);
    setTimeout(UU,0);
}

function GG(){
    $(".girl").animate({top: -121},1000).animate({top: -131},1000);
    setTimeout(GG,0);
}

function DD(){
    $(".card_down").animate({top: 20},2000).animate({top: 30},3000);
    setTimeout(DD,0);
}
UU();
GG();
DD();
```

Comment: Holy... really? Do you have any understanding of what your code is doing here? You're generating an endless string of animations!

Comment: How can i do? plz show me